# Laravel composer install error [golonka/BBcodeParser] 404

Tags: laravel, composer-php, http-status-code-404

I get error when run command:

```
composer install
```

Error:

```
 Installing golonka/bbcodeparser (v2.2.2): Downloading (failed)    Failed to download golonka/bbcodeparser from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/golonka/BBCodeParser/zipball/769c4ebe6207ffa20298b84b90eafca87ce2fb95" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
Now trying to download from source
```

This error occurs, because golonka/bbcodeparser no longer exist on github. How I can fix this error? Please help.

Comment: Take a look at its dependents, what kind of package they're replacing to now https://packagist.org/packages/golonka/bbcodeparser/dependents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's impossible. You cannot use package that was obviously removed from Github. It's in packagist but packagist doesn't contain source files so you should find another package that allows parsing BB code.

Comment: I removed vendor folder from project. And want reinstall. How I can do it?

Comment: As I said I think you cannot, if you don't have `vendor` directory saved somewhere you cannot do this. You can look at forks. For example `https://github.com/zwacky/BBCodeParser` might be a fork of golonka so you could try to use it instead of original package